# Create FTP virtual directory script

Tags: iis, ftp, virtual-directory

I am looking for a way to create a virtual ftp directory in IIS 5 and 6 via a script?

Does any one have such a script?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Courtesy of http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc739771%28WS.10%29.aspx

```
\Windows\Systm32\iisftpdr /create FTPSite[VirtualPath] Name PhysicalPath [/s Computer [/u [Domain\]User /p Password]
```

E.G.

```
iisftpdr /create "Test Downloads" Scripts C:\Libraries\Scripts
```

You could execute this via a batch file, or via a .vbs script.